# set HTML5 input list value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

I'm to create a html5 input field with an attached datalist by JavaScript. I'm not having any issues creating these dom nodes, but I am having trouble setting the `list` attribute value using pure JavaScript. Is this possible? I've checked the functionality of the node and the value of `list` is there, but whenever I try and set it no new value is assigned. Does anybody have any ideas?

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bkTxM/)'s an example in code.

```
var _form = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('form')),
    _input = _form.appendChild(document.createElement('input')),
    _datalist = _form.appendChild(document.createElement('datalist'));

_input.list = 'exampleList';
_input.datalist_id = 'exampleList';
_input.className = 'getme';

_datalist.id = 'exampleList';

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var _option = _datalist.appendChild(document.createElement('option'));
    switch(i){
        case i:
            _option.value = i;
            break;
    };
};
```

**Edit**

I have found a method of doing this via the `element.setAttribute();` method. How would one go about doing this in a syntax similar to (for example) `element.className = 'value';`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't make us go looking for your code. Please include it in the body of your question. By all means provide a fiddle in addition but always provide your code in the question. Make it as easy as possible for us to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I've just included the relevant sample.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) there is no property to set that attridute directly. So it looks like you're stuck with `setAttribute()`

You should also note that [DOM manipulations come with some performance ovehead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460727/jquery-dom-manipulations-performance-comparation) so it is some times best to minimise them. You might want to consider the following:

```
var _form = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('form')),
    _input = _form.appendChild(document.createElement('input')),
    _datalist = _form.appendChild(document.createElement('datalist'));


_datalist.id = 'exampleList';
_input.setAttribute('list','exampleList');

var _option = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    _option += "<option value='" + i + "' />";
};

_datalist.innerHTML = _option;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bkTxM/3/)

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't able to find anything so I was leaning towards that there was no method, but this confirms it. Thanks @Jon P. Your performance suggestion has also been noted :)

Answer (score 2):

Use setAttribute()  :

```
  var _form = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('form')),
    _input = _form.appendChild(document.createElement('input')),
    _datalist = _form.appendChild(document.createElement('datalist'));

_input.setAttribute('list','exampleList')
_input.datalist_id = 'exampleList';

_datalist.id = 'exampleList';

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var _option = _datalist.appendChild(document.createElement('option'));
    _option.text =i;   
};
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bkTxM/2/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am looking to use the HTML5 datalist however.

Comment: just before you posted your answer, I figured that I could set the list value using the `setAttribute` function. I'm looking to see if you can do it in the example I provided. If you also know how to do that, I would be appreciative!